# Картинка по android:background закрывает текст в Visual Studio. Почему?

Tags: android, visual-studio, background

Картинка background закрывает текст "Меня не видно !!!".
Как сделать фон и использовать текст, кнопки и другой контент без наложения этой картинки. Или может надо использовать что то иное для фона ?
Помогите плз новичку. Только начинаю обучаться.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/Background"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
    android:text="Меня не видно !!!"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Пока сидел появился ещё один вопросик: Как вернуть всплывающее окно с подсказкой в коде. что та типа всплывающей подсказки при нажатии ctrl+space, но та была гораздо более информативная.

Comment: скорее всего текст и фон одного цвета, в представленной разметке нет ничего, что бы закрывало текст

Comment: Нет. Фон вообще картинка jpg с текстурой и её видно, а вот текст под ней почему то. Т.е. в закладке Design если выбрат место где должен быть текст, то область текста выбирается и она под картинкой и текста не видно. Если картинку я делаю меньше то я вижу текст на чёрном (например) фоне.